# Dual Boot : Disk Failing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, disk

Upon logging into Ubuntu 18.04 I got a disk failing error. Upon some research on this particular problem, I conducted the smartctl self-assessment test which my disk failed. However, in the test it also says **No failed attributes found**. Here is a snapshot of the test results.

[image]

[image]

When I view my partitions using GParted, it displays my microsoft reserved partition as unknown.

[image]

In light of these of facts,
1. How likely is my disk to fail ?
2. What should be done to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smartctl overall-health self-assessment test returned this message:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment result: FAILED! 
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
```

SMART overall-health self-assessment test result that returns `FAILED` is almost always a sure indicator of failure.

Immediately stop using the hard drive because drive failure is expected in less than 24 hours, and save all data. Boot from the live DVD/USB that you used to install Ubuntu and backup all your personal files to an external hard drive. You should seriously consider getting an external hard drive for backup purposes if you don't already have one.

Comment: This means that the only way out is to replace my hard drive with a new one ?

Comment: The only way out is to **stop using the drive**, backup your data, and replace your hard drive with a new one.

Comment: One last question, I'm the event of changing to a new drive how do I install my copy of windows 10. Is there an option to create a recovery usb as it might ask for a product key when installing ?

Comment: 1. [How to Revive Windows 10 With a Recovery Drive](https://www.pcmag.com/feature/362167/how-to-revive-windows-10-with-a-recovery-drive) 2. [Create USB Recovery Drive For Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954856/)

Comment: a small side note. While backing up my windows 10 data I conducted tests from Hard Disk Sentinel on windows. It says performance and health at 100% stating the hard disk is perfect. Why is there a discrepancy ?

Comment: Hard Disk Sentinel monitors the same SMART. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology) as smartmontools from the default Ubuntu repositories.One of the two programs is returning a false negative.

Comment: Got it. Even though hds returns 100% on both ubuntu and windows I have still backed up my data to be safe. Still, I will continue using this disk, kind of curious to know which one is actually wrong ?